# find X-axis data points where horizontal line passes through on respective Y-axis value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a `[1,2,3,4,5]` data points on `x-axis`  and its respective value on `y-axis` like `[10,15,10,10,20]`. 
normally to find value point of `y-axis` by given `x-axis` data points
like `y=f(x)`, I checked this and we can achieve this by `interpolation` using `numpy`.. But I didn't found how to interpolate x-axis by given y-axis value.. as per attached screen I want to find respective x axis value where line `12` crosses..
so I am expecting result something like `[1, 1.x, 2, 2.x, 3, 4, 4.x, 5, 5.x]`   on `x-axis`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a smooth curve, you can use `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x + 0.1)

y0 = 0.3
spline = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y - y0)

xp = spline.roots()
```

Here is the plot:

```
pl.plot(x, y)
pl.axhline(0.3, color="black", linestyle="dashed")
pl.vlines(xp, 0, 0.3, color="gray", linestyle="dotted")
```

[image]

if you want linear interpolate:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 20)
y = np.sin(x + 0.1)
y0 = 0.3
y_offset = y - y0
pos = np.where((y_offset[1:] * y_offset[:-1]) <= 0)[0]

x1 = x[pos]
x2 = x[pos+1]
y1 = y[pos]
y2 = y[pos+1]

xp = (y0 - y1) / (y2 - y1) * (x2 - x1) + x1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you change `interp1d(x,y)` for `interp1d(y,x)` you have expressed x as a function of y.

Note that if f(x) is not unique, you may get unexpected or undefined behavior.